# WCF - Validation: Invalid token, How to redirect the message with exception details

Tags: wcf, wcf-security

I have implemented the members of **IdispatchMessageInspector** to validate the tokenId from the SOAP header. If the token is not valid, I would like redirect with error message. So that it would restrict to access the web methods. I don't know how to do it? Anybody done this before?

#region IDispatchMessageInspector Members

```
    public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message request, IClientChannel channel, InstanceContext instanceContext)
    {            

        if !(ValidateToken(tokenValue))
            //Redirect the error message 

        return null;
    }

    public void BeforeSendReply(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message reply, object correlationState)
    {
        //Log the Response with Log4Net or
        Console.WriteLine("IDispatchMessageInspector.BeforeSendReply called.");
    }
```

#endregion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Throwing an exception is right thing to do. Using [IErrorHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.ierrorhandler.handleerror.aspx) interface you can handle error on the service or let the host (IIS?) handle error (500).

Comment: peter,AfterReceiveRequest method, I called this throw:  throw new FaultException("Invalid TokenId"); Its redirecting to BeforeSendReply method. Is that enough? I dont know how to handle using IErrorHandler.

Comment: That's enough because channel and instance will be faulted. [Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/06/07/wcf-extensibility-ierrorhandler.aspx) is more detailed information on IErrorHandler